# Pagination not showing results after click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pagination, limit

This is a simple attempt at a pagination. Thought I would give it go with what I know. Now the page runs fine and I can scroll through the `LIMIT $startfrom`, `$displayto(amount)`

The thing is the 1st page shows the images, but once I clicked the button to move through the images I get no images? But when I clicked back I do, but only 3.

I am really not sure what is going on, but the pagination results are doing as should be (`0-5 , 5-5, 10,5 15,5 20,5)` etc.. But after 0,5 - no more images.

I'm posting the `$variables` also through `FORM`.

Also, when I browse DEV, I find that the dynamic images are not present after 1st page. But the LIMIT is correct and should be displaying as expected, Just no images for some odd reason. I presume its something to do with calling MYSQ manually for another run of the database, But I'm not sure as to why it would not do this through FORM POST anyway, as it recalls the whole script and page.

```
<?php

//
include ("conect.php");

if (isset($_POST['startfrom'])) {
$startfrom = htmlentities($_POST['startfrom'] ); };

if (isset($_POST['displayto'])) {
$displayto = htmlentities($_POST['displayto'] ); };

if (isset($_POST['resultcheck'])) {
$resultcheck = htmlentities($_POST['resultcheck'] ); };

if (isset($_POST['maxresults'])) {
$maxresults = htmlentities($_POST['maxresults'] ); };


if (empty($maxresults)) {$maxresults=5; }

if (empty($startfrom)) {$startfrom=0; };

if (empty($displayto)) {$displayto=5; };

if (empty($resultcheck)) {$resultcheck=0; };

if (!empty($resultcheck)) {$resultcheck=$resultcheck; };

if (!empty($startfrom)) {$startfrom=$startfrom; };

if (!empty($displayto)) {$displayto=$displayto; };

if (!empty($maxresults)) {$maxresults=$maxresults; }



if (isset($_POST['searchfor'])) {
$search = htmlentities($_POST['searchfor'] ); }


function ($search) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($search, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};

$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $search);

$search = filter_var($search, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (empty($search)) { $search="";};



if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
$location = htmlentities($_POST['location'] ); }


function ($location) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($location, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};

$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $location);

$location = filter_var($location, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//$location = strtolower($location);


if (empty($location)) { $location="";};



if (isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
$postcode = htmlentities($_POST['postcode'] ); }


function ($postcode) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($postcode, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};


$postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $postcode);

$postcode = filter_var($postcode, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


if (empty($postcode)) { $postcode="";};





if (isset($_POST['price'])) {
$price = htmlentities($_POST['price'] ); }


function ($price) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($price, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};


$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $price);

$price = filter_var($price, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



if (empty($price)) { $price="";};





if (isset($_POST['catagory'])) {
$catagory = htmlentities($_POST['catagory'] ); }


function ($catagory) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($catagory, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};


$catagory = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $catagory);

$catagory = filter_var($catagory, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



if (empty($catagory)) {$catagory="";};



    if ($resultcheck<1) {

if (empty($postcode)) { 

if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata 
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' 

OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%'  
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' 
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%'


";
};



if (empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' OR locate ='%%$location%%' ORDER BY price DESC

";
};







if (empty($search) && empty($location)) { 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' ORDER BY price DESC

";
};


if (!empty($search) && empty($location)) { 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' ORDER BY price DESC

";
};

};



if (!empty($postcode)) {    

if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata 
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
ORDER BY price DESC 

";
};



if (empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' 
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='%%$location%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
ORDER BY price DESC
";
};

if (empty($search) && empty($location)) { 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' OR postcode='%%$postcode%%'
ORDER BY price DESC
";
};



if (!empty($search) && empty($location)) { 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
ORDER BY price DESC
";
};

};




$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;



$maxresults=$row_cnt;


 $resultcheck="1";
}; //if empty resultcheck






 if ($resultcheck=1 OR $resultcheck>1) {

if (empty($postcode)) { 

if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata 
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' 
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%'  
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' 
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT $startfrom,$displayto
";
};



if (empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' OR locate ='%%$location%%' ORDER B price DESC LIMIT $startfrom,$displayto
";
};




if (empty($search) && empty($location)) { 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT $startfrom,$displayto
";
};



if (empty($location) && !empty($search))";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT $startfrom,$displayto 
";
};

};



if (!empty($postcode)) {    

if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 
//echo "1. if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata 
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT $startfrom,$displayto 

";
};



if (empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' 
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='%%$location%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT $startfrom,$displayto

";
};


if (empty($search) && empty($location)) { 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' OR postcode='%%$postcode%%' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT $startfrom,$displayto 

";
};


if (!empty($search) && empty($location)) { 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT $startfrom,$displayto  

";
};

 };

$result = $conn->query($sql);



$resultcheck=2;

 };

  echo" <div class='searchresults'> ";
    printf("Search Results for {$search} in {$catagory} Within {$location} & Totals %d results {$displayto}&{$startfrom} <br><br>", $maxresults);
 echo" </div>";



while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {             //  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



$vid = $row['id']; //<!---important is Video ID and needed for video click selection---->
$type = $row['type'];
$id = $row['id'];
$vidd= $row['id']-0.01;
$pidd= $row['id']-0.02;
$name = $row['Name'];
$image = $row['image']; 
$info = $row['info'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$title = $row['title'];
$locate = $row['locate'];
$postcoded = $row['postcode'];
$price = $row['price'];
$videos = $row['videos'];
$date = $row['stamp'];
$type = $row['type'];
$showinglocate=$row['id']-0.03;
$showingphone=$row['id']-0.04;

echo"                                      

<div class='floater'>


<div style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:99%; border-radius: 1vw; box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #aaa; background-color:white; overflow:hidden;'>


";


 if (empty($videos) && empty($image)) {

     echo "<img src='image/blank.png' style='position:absolute; top:18%; left:10%; width:80%; height:68%; opacity:0.5; transform: scale(1.0,1.1);'>
    "; }


     if (!empty($videos)) { 

           echo "

           <video id='$vidd' title='{$row['title']} {$row['locate']}' style='position:absolute; top:18%; left:0%; width:100%; height:60%; transform: scale(1.0,1.1);' preload='metadata' controls='controls'>

                 <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
                  <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/ogg'>
                   <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/webm'>


                 </video >


                 <div id='vidicon' title='Video's' class='vidicon' ondblclick='controlshowvid($vidd , $pidd);' ><img src='pageimages/vidicon.jpg' style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1; cursor:hand;'></div>

          "; }

          if (!empty($image)) { 
                    echo "<img id='$pidd' src='image/{$row['image']}' style='position:absolute; top:18%; left:0%; width:100%; height:60%; transform: scale(1.0,1.1);'>
                    <div id='pictureicon' title='Pictures' class='pictureicon' ondblclick='controlshowimage($vidd , $pidd);'><img src='pageimages/pictureicon.jpg' style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1; cursor:hand;'></div>

                         "; }






echo "

<div id='displaytitle' style='position:absolute; top:3%; left:1%; width:100%;'><font style='font-size:1.4em;color:blue'><center>{$row['title']}</center></div></font>

<div id='displaystamp' title='{$row['stamp']}'style='position:absolute; top:9.0%; left:3%; width:30%; text-align:left;'><font style='color:grey; font-size:0.6em;'>{$row['stamp']}</div><br></font>

<div id='displaypostcode' title='{$row['postcode']}' style='position:absolute; top:9%; left:84.8%; width:16.2%; '><font style='color:grey; font-size:0.7em;'>{$row['postcode']}</div><br></font>





<div id='displayprice' style='position:absolute; top:90%; left:2%; text-align:center; border-radius: 1vw; box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px #aaa;'><font style='color:blue;'><center><strong>£{$row['price']}</strong></center></div>

<div id='$showinglocate' title='{$row['postcode']}' style='position:absolute; top:82%; left:0%; width:100%; Z-index:15; cursor:hand;' ondblclick='changeshowdetail($showinglocate, $showingphone)' ><font style='color:black'><center><strong>{$row['locate']}</strong></center></div>
<div id='$showingphone' title='{$row['Name']}' style='position:absolute; top:82%; left:0%; width:100%; visibility:hidden; cursor:hand; ' ondblclick='changeshowdetail2($showinglocate,$showingphone)' ><font style='color:black'><center><strong>{$row['phone']}</strong></center></div>


<div id='showwhole' class='showwhole' title='Click to View' ondblclick='' ><font style='font-size:0.8em; #ddd'>View Full Page</font></div>






</div> 
</div> 


";

}
?>


</div>

</div>

    </div>          


<div class="footer">


<form id='sendpaginationforward' action='linkdsearch.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='startfrom' value='<?php echo $startfrom = $startfrom +5 ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='displayto' value='<?php echo $displayto = 5 ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='searchfor' value='<?php echo $search ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='price' value='<?php echo $price ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='catagory' value='<?php echo $catagory ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='location' value='<?php echo $location ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='resultcheck' value='<?php echo $resultcheck ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='postcode' value='<?php echo $postcode ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='maxresults' value='<?php echo $maxresults ?>' />

<input type='hidden' type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>


<form id='sendpaginationback' action='linkdsearch.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='startfrom2' value='<?php echo $startfrom = $startfrom -5 ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='displayto2' value='<?php echo $displayto = 5 ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='searchfor' value='<?php echo $search ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='price' value='<?php echo $price ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='catagory' value='<?php echo $catagory ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='location' value='<?php echo $location ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='resultcheck' value='<?php echo $resultcheck ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='postcode' value='<?php echo $postcode ?>' />
<input type='hidden' type='text' name='maxresults' value='<?php echo $maxresults ?>' />

<input type='hidden' type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>


<img src="pageimages/pictureicon.jpg" ondblclick="changeamountdisplay2();" style='position:absolute; left:20%;'>
<img src="pageimages/vidicon.jpg" ondblclick="changeamountdisplay();" style='position:absolute; left:80%;'>

<p> display<?php echo $displayto; ?> </p>
<p> start from<?php echo $startfrom; ?> </p> 
<p> max<?php echo $maxresults; ?> </p>
<p> check<?php echo $resultcheck; ?> </p>
</div>



</div>



<script>
function changeamountdisplay(){
document.getElementById('sendpaginationforward').submit(); return false;
};
</script>

<script>
function changeamountdisplay2(){
document.getElementById('sendpaginationback').submit(); return false;
};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeshowdetail(showinglocate,showingphone)
    {
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.opacity=('0.0'); 
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.visibility=('hidden');
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.Zindex=('-1'); 

    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.opacity=('1.1');
    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.Zindex=('10');
        document.getElementById(showingphone).style.visibility=('visible'); 
};
function changeshowdetail2(showinglocate,showingphone)
{       
    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.opacity=('0.0'); 
    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.Zindex=('-1');
    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.visibility=('hidden');

    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.opacity=('1.1');
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.visibility=('visible');
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.Zindex=('10'); 

};

</script>

<script>

function controlshowvid(vidd,pidd){
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.opacity=('0.0'); 
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.visibility=('hidden');
    document.getElementById(vidd).style.opacity=('1.1');

    document.getElementById(vidd).style.Zindex=('15');
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.Zindex=('-1'); 
};


function controlshowimage(vidd,pidd){
    document.getElementById(vidd).style.opacity=('0.0'); 
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.opacity=('1.1');
        document.getElementById(pidd).style.visibility=('visible');
    document.getElementById(vidd).style.Zindex=('-1');
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.Zindex=('15'); 

};
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

In fact come to think of it, I would of been better simply doing an image scroller rather than paginant. I shall look into it. But I definitely want to know how to complete a pagination. But if anybody has a simple image rotation to offer, I would be most greatfull.

Answer (score 0):

After a good bit of trial&error, i eventually managed to accomplish what i had set out to do. The main reason for the code not working initially was because the Search variables where being updated from the last database $data for the last video/image/price/locate/info/ect ect. so the variables sent to the form where of the last image/video, instead of the search field.... I amended this to remove the variable being POSTed to the form , and initializing !isset & !empty to set the variables before query and after POST, therefor the variables where then being updated with the search query data rather than the image/video data. So finally after a little tweaking of the code i have it up and running...

Thanks for any interest. i hope this simple pagination will help somebody else 1 day.

Heres the Final Code..

```
<?php

//
include ("conect.php");



if (!isset($_POST['direction'])) {
$direction = "1";}


if (!isset($_POST['searchfor'])) {
$search = "";}


if (!isset($_POST['location'])) {
$location = "";}


if (!isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
$postcode = "";}


if (!isset($_POST['price'])) {
$price = "";}


if (!isset($_POST['catagory'])) {
$catagory = "";}


$display=9;


if (empty($maxresults)) {$maxresults=$display; }


if (empty($direction)) {$direction=1; }


if (!empty($direction)) {$direction=$direction; }



if (empty($startfrom)) {$startfrom=0; };

if (empty($displayto)) {$displayto=$display; };

if (empty($resultcheck)) {$resultcheck=0; };

if (!empty($resultcheck)) {$resultcheck=$resultcheck; };

if (!empty($startfrom)) {$startfrom=$startfrom; };

if (!empty($displayto)) {$displayto=$displayto; };

if (!empty($maxresults)) {$maxresults=$maxresults; }








if (isset($_POST['startfrom'])) {
$startfrom = htmlentities($_POST['startfrom'] ); };

if (isset($_POST['displayto'])) {
$displayto = htmlentities($_POST['displayto'] ); };

if (isset($_POST['resultcheck'])) {
$resultcheck = htmlentities($_POST['resultcheck'] ); };

if (isset($_POST['maxresults'])) {
$maxresults = htmlentities($_POST['maxresults'] ); };


if (isset($_POST['searchfor'])) {
$search = htmlentities($_POST['searchfor'] ); }

if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
$location = htmlentities($_POST['location'] ); }


if (isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
$postcode = htmlentities($_POST['postcode'] ); }


if (isset($_POST['price'])) {
$price = htmlentities($_POST['price'] ); }


if (isset($_POST['catagory'])) {
$catagory = htmlentities($_POST['catagory'] ); }




if (isset($_POST['direction'])) {
$direction = htmlentities($_POST['direction'] ); }


//use this for any input to be stored in the database - to eliminate any html or script tags
function ($direction) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($search, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};

//escape chars - basically escapes such chars as ' or " or # ect ect with a slash//
$direction = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $direction);

$direction = filter_var($direction, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);






//set error for null value - error to give value a return of 1


if (isset($_POST['searchfor'])) {
$search = htmlentities($_POST['searchfor'] ); }


//use this for any input to be stored in the database - to eliminate any html or script tags
function ($search) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($search, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};

//escape chars - basically escapes such chars as ' or " or # ect ect with a slash//
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $search);

$search = filter_var($search, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



if (empty($search)) { $search="";};
//$search = strtolower($search);




if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
$location = htmlentities($_POST['location'] ); }


//use this for any input to be stored in the database - to eliminate any html or script tags
function ($location) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($location, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};

//escape chars - basically escapes such chars as ' or " or # ect ect with a slash//
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $location);

$location = filter_var($location, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//$location = strtolower($location);


if (empty($location)) { $location="";};



if (isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
$postcode = htmlentities($_POST['postcode'] ); }


//use this for any input to be stored in the database - to eliminate any html or script tags
function ($postcode) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($postcode, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};

//escape chars - basically escapes such chars as ' or " or # ect ect with a slash//
$postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $postcode);

$postcode = filter_var($postcode, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//$postcode = strtolower($postcode);


if (empty($postcode)) { $postcode="";};





if (isset($_POST['price'])) {
$price = htmlentities($_POST['price'] ); }


//use this for any input to be stored in the database - to eliminate any html or script tags
function ($price) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($price, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};

//escape chars - basically escapes such chars as ' or " or # ect ect with a slash//
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $price);

$price = filter_var($price, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//$postcode = strtolower($postcode);


if (empty($price)) { $price="";};





if (isset($_POST['catagory'])) {
$catagory = htmlentities($_POST['catagory'] ); }


//use this for any input to be stored in the database - to eliminate any html or script tags
function ($catagory) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($catagory, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
};

//escape chars - basically escapes such chars as ' or " or # ect ect with a slash//
$catagory = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $catagory);

$catagory = filter_var($catagory, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//$catagory = strtolower($catagory);


if (empty($catagory)) {$catagory="";};









//search according to chosen search critera NOT LIMITED//


    if ($resultcheck<1) {





if ($displayto>$maxresults) {$displayto=$maxresults;};

if ($startfrom>$maxresults-$displayto) {$startfrom=$maxresults-$displayto;};
if ($startfrom>$maxresults) {$startfrom=$maxresults-$displayto;};

if ($startfrom<0){$startfrom=0;};


if ($displayto<0) {$displayto=0;};


    //echo "D2{$displayto} D{$display} M{$maxresults} S{$startfrom} DIR {$direction}";


    if ($direction=1 && $startfrom<0) {$startfrom=0;};


if (empty($postcode)) { 

if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 
//echo "1. if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata 
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' 

OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%'  
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' 
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%'


";
};


if (empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' OR locate ='%%$location%%'

";
};






// checks for an empty search value 
if (empty($search) && empty($location)) { 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' 

";
};






// checks for an empty search value LIMIT 15  1
if (!empty($search) && empty($location)) { 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' 

";
};

};


if (!empty($postcode)) {    

if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 
//echo "1. if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata 
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'


";
};

//  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $catagory 
// WHERE locate LIKE '%%$location%%'ate LIKE '%%$location%%' most recent and working //

if (empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 
//echo "2. if (empty($search) && !empty($location))";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' 
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='%%$location%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'

";
};

// checks for an empty search value 
if (empty($search) && empty($location)) { 
//echo "3. if (empty($search) && empty($location))";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' OR postcode='%%$postcode%%'

";
};


// checks for an empty search value LIMIT 15  1
if (!empty($search) && empty($location)) { 
//echo "4. if (empty($location) && !empty($search))";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'

";
};

};




$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;



if ($resultcheck<1) {$maxresults=$row_cnt;};

 $resultcheck="1";
}; //if empty resultcheck






 //if $resultcheck not empty 


 if ($resultcheck=1 OR $resultcheck>1) {
 $maxresults=$maxresults;




if ($displayto>$maxresults) {$displayto=$maxresults;};

if ($startfrom>$maxresults-$displayto) {$startfrom=$maxresults-$displayto;};
if ($startfrom>$maxresults) {$startfrom=$maxresults-$displayto;};

if ($startfrom<0){$startfrom=0;};


if ($displayto<0) {$displayto=0;};

if ($direction=1 && $startfrom<0) {$startfrom=0;};





 //search results WITH LIMIT $startfrom  , $displayto 
if (empty($postcode)) { 

if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 
//echo "1. if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata 
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto
";
};

//  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $catagory 
// WHERE locate LIKE '%%$location%%' OR locate = '%%$location%%' most recent and working //






if (empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 
//echo "2. if (empty($search) && !empty($location))";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' OR locate ='%%$location%%' LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto
";
};






// checks for an empty search value 
if (empty($search) && empty($location)) { 
//echo "3. if (empty($search) && empty($location))";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto
";
};






// checks for an empty search value LIMIT 15 , 1
if (!empty($search) && empty($location)) { 
//echo "4. if (empty($location) && !empty($search))";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto
";
};

};



if (!empty($postcode)) {    

if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 
//echo "1. if (!empty($search) && !empty($location)) ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata 
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='$location' AND type LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto

";
};

//  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $catagory 
// WHERE locate LIKE '%%$location%%'ate LIKE '%%$location%%' most recent and working //

if (empty($search) && !empty($location)) { 
//echo "2. if (empty($search) && !empty($location))";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND locate LIKE '%%$location%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND locate='%%$location%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto

";
};

// checks for an empty search value 
if (empty($search) && empty($location)) { 
//echo "3. if (empty($search) && empty($location))";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR postcode='%%$postcode%%' LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto

";
};


// checks for an empty search value LIMIT 15 , 1
if (!empty($search) && empty($location)) { 
//echo "4. if (empty($location) && !empty($search))";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE price LIKE '%%$price%%' AND type LIKE '%%$catagory%%' AND title LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%'
OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' AND postcode LIKE '%%$postcode%%' LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto

";
};

 };

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$resultcheck=2;



  echo" <center><div class='searchresults'> ";
    printf("Search Results for {$search} in {$catagory} Within {$location} & Totals %d results {$displayto}&{$startfrom} <br><br>", $maxresults);
 echo" </div> </center>";



while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {             //  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



$vid = $row['id']; //<!---important is Video ID and needed for video click selection---->
$type = $row['type'];
$id = $row['id'];
$vidd= $row['id']-0.01;
$pidd= $row['id']-0.02;
$name = $row['Name'];
$image = $row['image']; 
$info = $row['info'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$title = $row['title'];
$locate = $row['locate'];
$postcoded = $row['postcode'];
$price = $row['price'];
$videos = $row['videos'];
$date = $row['stamp'];
$type = $row['type'];
$showinglocate=$row['id']-0.03;
$showingphone=$row['id']-0.04;

echo"                                      

<center>

<div class='floater'>


<div style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:auto; margin:0 auto; display:table; width:100%; height:99%; border-radius: 1vw; box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #aaa; background-color:white; overflow:hidden;'>


";


 if (empty($videos) && empty($image)) {

     echo "<img src='image/blank.png' style='position:absolute; top:18%; left:10%; width:80%; height:68%; opacity:0.5; transform: scale(1.0,1.1);'>
    "; }


     if (!empty($videos)) { 

           echo "

           <video id='$vidd' title='{$row['title']} {$row['locate']}' style='position:absolute; left:0px; top:18%; width:100%; height:60%; transform: scale(1.0,1.1);' preload='metadata' controls='controls'>

                 <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
                  <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/ogg'>
                   <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/webm'>


                 </video >


                 <div id='vidicon' title='Video's' class='vidicon' ondblclick='controlshowvid($vidd , $pidd);' ><img src='pageimages/vidicon.jpg' style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1; cursor:hand;'></div>

         "; }

          if (!empty($image)) { 
                    echo "<img id='$pidd' src='image/{$row['image']}' style='position:absolute; top:18%; left:0%; width:100%; height:60%; transform: scale(1.0,1.1);'>
                    <div id='pictureicon' title='Pictures' class='pictureicon' ondblclick='controlshowimage($vidd , $pidd);'><img src='pageimages/pictureicon.jpg' style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1; cursor:hand;'></div>

                         "; }






echo "

<div id='displaytitle' class='displaytitle' ><center>{$row['title']}</center></div></font>

<div id='displaystamp' class='displaystamp' title='{$row['stamp']}'>{$row['stamp']}</div><br></font>

<div id='displaypostcode' class='displaypostcode' title='{$row['postcode']}' >{$row['postcode']}</div><br></font>




<div id='displayprice'><center><strong>£{$row['price']}</strong></center></div>

<div id='$showinglocate' class='showinglocate' style=' 'title='{$row['postcode']}'  ondblclick='changeshowdetail($showinglocate, $showingphone)' ><center><strong>{$row['locate']}</strong></center></div>
<div id='$showingphone' class='showingphone' style=' ' title='{$row['Name']}' ondblclick='changeshowdetail2($showinglocate,$showingphone)' ><center><strong>{$row['phone']}</strong></center></div>


<div id='showwhole' class='showwhole' title='View Details Page' ondblclick='' ><img src='pageimages/pageicon.jpg' style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1; cursor:hand;'> <div>






</div> 

</div> 
</center>



";

}
};
?>

<br>


    <div class="footer">


        <form id='sendpaginationforward' type='submit' action='linkdsearchpagination.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
        <input type='hidden' type='submit' name='startfrom' value='<?php echo $startfrom+$display?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submit' name='displayto' value='<?php echo $display ?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submit' name='resultcheck' value='<?php echo $resultcheck=2 ?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submit' name='maxresults' value='<?php echo $maxresults ?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submmit' name='$direction' value='<?php echo 2 ?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submit' action='submit'>
        </form>


        <form id='sendpaginationback' type='submit' action='linkdsearchpagination.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
        <input type='hidden' type='submit' name='startfrom' value='<?php echo $startfrom-$display?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submit' name='displayto' value='<?php echo $display ?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submit' name='resultcheck' value='<?php echo $resultcheck=2 ?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submmit' name='maxresults' value='<?php echo $maxresults ?>' />

        <input type='hidden' type='submmit' name='$direction' value='<?php echo 1 ?>' />



        <input type='hidden' type='submit' action="submit">
        </form>


        <img src="pageimages/pictureicon.jpg" ondblclick="changeamountdisplay2();" style='position:relative; float:left; bottom:78%; height:80%;margin:10px; z-index:100;'>
        <center style="position:relative; top:-30%; left:-3.4%; float:top; "><font style='font-size: 2vw; color:blue;'>Showing Results  &nbsp <?php echo 1+$startfrom ?>&nbsp to <?php echo $startfrom+$displayto ?>  &nbsp of &nbsp<?php echo $maxresults ?></font></center>
        <img src="pageimages/vidicon.jpg" ondblclick="changeamountdisplay();" style='position:relative; float:right; bottom:134%; height:80%; margin:10px; z-index:100;'>


    </div>



  </div>

 </div>

</div>          





</div>



<script>
function changeamountdisplay(){

document.getElementById('sendpaginationforward').submit(); return false;
};
</script>

<script>
function changeamountdisplay2(){

document.getElementById('sendpaginationback').submit(); return false;
};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeshowdetail(showinglocate,showingphone)
    {
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.opacity=('0.0'); 
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.visibility=('hidden');
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.Zindex=('-1'); 

    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.opacity=('1.1');
    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.Zindex=('10');
        document.getElementById(showingphone).style.visibility=('visible'); 
};
function changeshowdetail2(showinglocate,showingphone)
{       
    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.opacity=('0.0'); 
    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.Zindex=('-1');
    document.getElementById(showingphone).style.visibility=('hidden');

    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.opacity=('1.1');
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.visibility=('visible');
    document.getElementById(showinglocate).style.Zindex=('10'); 

};

</script>

<script>

function controlshowvid(vidd,pidd){
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.opacity=('0.0'); 
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.visibility=('hidden');
    document.getElementById(vidd).style.opacity=('1.1');

    document.getElementById(vidd).style.Zindex=('15');
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.Zindex=('-1'); 
};


function controlshowimage(vidd,pidd){
    document.getElementById(vidd).style.opacity=('0.0'); 
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.opacity=('1.1');
        document.getElementById(pidd).style.visibility=('visible');
    document.getElementById(vidd).style.Zindex=('-1');
    document.getElementById(pidd).style.Zindex=('15'); 

};
</script>

</body>

</html>
```